# Html interaction with smart contract via web3.js

Tags: web3js, testrpc

I have a html code interacting with my smart contract via a local test rpc local host.

I was just wondering if I deploy this contract to the main network instead of using test rpc, what should be the http provider I specify in my html code?

As well as would the user whom will interact with the html page need to have a test rpc running as well.

```
   <script>
   if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined' && typeof window.web3.currentProvider !== "undefined")
   {
     console.log(typeof web3)
     web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider );
   } else {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case where your machine (node) is connected to the main network you can keep the local http provider (localhost:8545). Otherwise you can use an online http provider as [infura servers](https://blog.infura.io/getting-started-with-infura-28e41844cc89).

> As well as would the user whom will interact with the html page need
>   to have a test rpc running as well.

testrpc is just for testing purposes (running a local blockchain like localhost) so users either use their nodes connected to main network (which is not practical i guess) or you use infura or other online nodes which connect them directly to the network.